# Solving linear PDEs in the distribution sense (confusion about the notation)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

After defining convolutions of two tempered distributions $T,S \in \mathcal{S}'$;  and convolutions of functions $f \in \mathcal{S}$ with distributions $T \in \mathcal{S}'$, my textbook goes on to discuss their application to solving linear PDEs, in particular it claims that for the PDE:

$$ D u = f  $$

The solution is, in the distribution sense, $u = f * g$ with $g : \ Dg = \delta$. (here the notation is "abused")

**My question:** How does one convert a "normal" PDE to a "distribution" PDE ? What did my textbook mean to say ? Is $Du =f$  :

$$ \langle  D T_u, \phi \rangle = \langle T_f , \phi \rangle  \ ? $$

or is it:

$$ \langle  D T_u, \phi \rangle = f \ ? $$

Answer (score 1):

Your textbook means that $u$ is a distribution such that $\langle Du, \phi \rangle = \langle T_f, \phi \rangle$ for every test function $\phi$.

What would the formula $\langle DT_u, \phi \rangle = f$ mean? The left hand side is a number, while the right hand side is a function.

---

**An example**

In 3 dimensions, one has
$$
\Delta G(x) = \delta
$$
where $\Delta$ is the [Laplace operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator), $G(x)=\frac{1}{4\pi\|x\|},$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$ with $\|x\| = \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}.$

A solution to $\Delta u = \rho,$ where $u$ and $\rho$ are distributions, is then given by
$$
u = G*\rho
.
$$
Often both $u$ and $\rho$ are induced by ordinary functions and the convolution is then defined in both a classical sense (i.e. using an integral) and in the distributional sense. To be more precise, if $f$ and $g$ are functions so that $f*g$ is defined using the integral definition, then $T_f*T_g = T_{f*g}$ in the distributional sense.

Comment: yes that makes perfect sense... by $Du$ you mean $DT_u$ ,no ? ( $T_u$ defined as $\int_{\mathbb{R}} u \phi dx$)

Comment: No, I mean that $u$ is a distribution, not a function. The notation $T_u$ normally means that $u$ is a function and $T_u$ the corresponding distribution.

Comment: ah ok !!, so one could write $u$ as $T$ making things absolutely clear ( usually just $u$ means $T_u$ )

Comment: If you are more used to $T$ as a notation for distributions, then do it.

Comment: @lohey. I added an example.

Comment: ty for the example , in the last paragraph (Often both $u$ and $\rho$...)  you mean to say that when we have an ordinary EDP (i.e. with  functions $u, \rho $) then one can associate $u \rightarrow T_u = \int u \phi dx$  (as long as that integral makes sense) and write the "distribution " EDP as:$ \langle  \Delta T_u , \phi \rangle = \langle T_{\rho}, \phi \rangle$. Is that correct ? sorry for the confusion...

Comment: @lohey. Yes, and we can have both $\Delta u = \rho$ in the classical sense and $\Delta T_u = T_\rho$ in the distributional sense.